# Is it better to pass a connection object to a module or to connect within the module itself?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

```
var redis = require('redis');
var http = require('http');
var myModule = require('./my_module');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  myModule.something_that_uses_redis(req, redis, function(data) {
    res.end(data);
  });
});
```

Is it better to define `redis` outside the module and pass it in whenever needed or is it better to define it somewhere inside `myModule`? Will passing it as an argument cause some sort of unneeded stress or are both methods about the same?

Is there a best practice regarding this?

I'm re-writing an API that's unexpectedly receiving a huge number of requests and I'm trying to understand what types of things cause unnecessary processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are creating an instance of say a redis client, then you are better sharing the instance, rather than creating a new instance each time. Otherwise, you have the overheads of creating a new connection each time.

In your example though, you are only requiring the module, and as this is cached on the first require, it makes little difference if you require in only once in myModule and pass by reference, or require it separately each module.

For this specific example, from past experience I'd create one redis client in a separate module, put all the logic that accesses this client in functions in that module, and call these functions from myModule. That was your database logic has a degree of decoupling from the application. That way if the database changes, you need only change the functions in your module that accesses Redis, and not changing code in lots of different files.

Answer (score 1):

If `my_module` is the only module using Redis, it makes more sense to me to have it set up and handle the connection itself.

If there are multiple modules that require access to Redis, I would probably create a separate module for it that other modules can `require`.